# How to find average of two lines in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to find average of two values in separate lines.

My CSV file looks like this

```
Name,ID,Marks
Mahi,1,90
Mahi,1,100


Andy,2,85
Andy,2,95
```

Now I need to store that average of 2 marks in database.
"Average" column should add two marks and divide with 2 and store that result in SQL query

Table:

```
Name,ID,Average
Mahi,2,95
Andy,2,90
```

Is it possible to find the average of two values in separate rows using NiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a *lot* of assumptions, this is doable. You are definitely better off pre-processing the data in NiFi and exporting it to a tool better suited to this, like [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) using the [NiFi Spark Receiver](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-external/nifi-spark-receiver) library ([instructions here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/12708/nifi-feeding-data-to-spark-streaming.html)), because this solution will not scale well.

However, you could certainly use a combination of `SplitText` processors to get the proper data into individual flowfiles (i.e. all *Mahi* rows in one, all *Andy* rows in another). Once you have a record that looks like:

```
Andy,1,85
Andy,1,95
```

you can use `ExtractText` with regular expressions to get `85` and `95` into attributes `marks.1` and `marks.2` (a good example of where scaling will break down -- doing this with 2 rows is easy; doing this with 100k is ridiculous). You can then use `UpdateAttribute` with the Expression Language to calculate the average of those two attributes (convert `toNumber()` first) and populate a third attribute `marks.average` (either through chaining `plus()` and `divide()` functions or with the [`math` advanced operation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#math) (uses Java Reflection)). Once you have the desired result in an attribute, use `ReplaceText` to update the flowfile content, and `MergeContent` to merge the individual flowfiles back into a single instance.

If this were me, I'd first evaluate how static my incoming data format was, and if it was guaranteed to stay the same, probably just write a Groovy script that parsed the data and calculated the averages in place. I think that would even scale better (within reason) because of the flexibility of having written domain-specific code. If you need to offload this to cluster operations, Spark is the way to go.